# How to display decimal places in group statetement in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT date,

       type,

       id,

       process,

       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.90) within group(ORDER BY duration/60000) OVER (PARTITION BY date,type,id,process) AS top90

FROM table
```

It returned like follow.

```
date       id    type  process top90
2021-05-19  a      X    A       6
2021-05-19  b      Y            
2021-05-19  c      Z    A       7
```

But my desired result is like following to display up to 2 decimal places.

```
date       id    type  process top90
2021-05-19  a      X    A       6.36
2021-05-19  b      Y            
2021-05-19  c      Z    A       7.42
```

I tried `cast(duration/60000,real)` but it returned same result..

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If `duration` is an `integer` or `bigint`, `duration / 60000` will be an integer division and truncate the result.

   Use `duration / 60000.0` to avoid that.
2. `percentile_disc` will return the existing value closest to the specified percentile. Use `percentile_cont` to interpolate.